# Simulate mouse ScrollUp using Selenium in Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium, mousewheel

Hello I'm trying to simulate a "natural" scroll of mouse using Selenium with PhantomJs in Python.

I want to scrollup emulating the mouse wheel in  order to come back to the page.
Is possibile do this with JavaScript? 
Actualy i use this command in order to scroll on the bottom of the page.

```
self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

So I think that is possible run some script like this in order to go up simulating the fluency of the Mouse.

Comment: Have you been able to solve the problem so far :) ?

Comment: @SIslam Nope the only think i find similar is this:
self.driver.execute_script("$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 2000);")

But it works only if the website implemnts animate function

Comment: could you post the site link to give me a clear idea.

Comment: @SIslam http://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2/

Comment: Ah! I sought for site to be under test.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you did not posted what you tried so far- By the way.

Following coding style works for me- there may be better practice.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=a1+plumbing+boise")


link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('View all Google reviews')
link.click()


try:
    print "about to look for element"
    def find(driver):
        e = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME ,'_wu')
        if (e.get_attribute("disabled")=='true'):
            return False
        return e
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(find)
    print "still looking?"
finally: print 'yowp'

nam = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME ,'_wu')

#get length of review
revcnt = driver.find_element(By.XPATH ,"//span[@class='_Mnc _yz']")
revcnt = int(revcnt.text.replace(" reviews","").strip())
print revcnt
# wait for reviews to appear
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.review-snippet")))#review-snippet
cntr = 0
reviews = []
while True:#cntr<=revcnt:
    global cntr
    reviews = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div._ju")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", reviews[-1])
    print len(reviews)
    cntr+=1
    if len(reviews) == revcnt:
        break

mores  = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='fl review-more-link']")
for more in mores:
    more.click()

js_code = "return document.getElementsByClassName('_ju');"
your_elements = driver.execute_script(js_code)

#print len(your_elements)
for i in your_elements:
    print i.text.encode('utf-8') 

driver.quit()
```